# Оптимизация запроса update в mysql

Tags: update, mysql

Добрый день! Мне необходимо сделать 2 записи в бд. Можно ли их как-то объединить в одну?
И выиграем ли мы в производительности, объединив эти запросы? Спасибо

```
$query="UPDATE $table1
SET pokaz='1', coin=coin+1, vote=vote+1
WHERE id='$id1'";//обновление таблицы 1ой
$res = mysql_query($query); 
 $query="UPDATE $table1
SET pokaz='1'
WHERE id='$id2'";//обновление таблицы 2ой
$res = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Одна таблица, две записи, именно эти запросы нет смысла объединять. Так будет нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Объединять их нет смысла. Нужно завернуть код в транзакцию, и заэкранировать переменные `$id1` и `$id2`.